# When is a child socket created on a receiving side during a 3wh process, given syncookies are not used?

Tags: linux, sockets, linux-kernel

That's the main question. But in order for a reply would be meaningful for
me, there are several other questions I should ask. So, here is a bit more
detailed version: what I've found out about a 3wh so far, and questions
left along the way.

When a client initiates a 3wh, it sends a syn packet to the server. There,
the TCP layer’s entrypoint is a [tcp_v4_rcv](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4d6d4c7f541d7027beed4fb86eb2c451bd8d6fff/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c#L1975)
procedure. When a packet is received, a [listening socket is looked up](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4d6d4c7f541d7027beed4fb86eb2c451bd8d6fff/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c#L2017). If it’s found, I guess its state is [TCP_LISTEN](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4d6d4c7f541d7027beed4fb86eb2c451bd8d6fff/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c#L2132). Through a [tcp_v4_do_rcv()](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4d6d4c7f541d7027beed4fb86eb2c451bd8d6fff/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c#L2133) helper procedure, we reach [tcp_rcv_state_process()](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4d6d4c7f541d7027beed4fb86eb2c451bd8d6fff/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c#L1744). There, I think I fall into [this clause](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4d6d4c7f541d7027beed4fb86eb2c451bd8d6fff/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c#L6478). Then, through a [tcp_v4_conn_request()](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4d6d4c7f541d7027beed4fb86eb2c451bd8d6fff/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c#L1529) procedure I find myself in [tcp_conn_request()](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4d6d4c7f541d7027beed4fb86eb2c451bd8d6fff/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c#L6924).
I'm interested in a case when syncookies are not used, so the want_cookie
variable remains false. A request socket [is created](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4d6d4c7f541d7027beed4fb86eb2c451bd8d6fff/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c#L6957). Its ireq_state is
[TCP_NEW_SYN_RECV](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4d6d4c7f541d7027beed4fb86eb2c451bd8d6fff/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c#L6815), a [listener socket is attached](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4d6d4c7f541d7027beed4fb86eb2c451bd8d6fff/include/net/request_sock.h#L101) and a [syn-packet
saved](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4d6d4c7f541d7027beed4fb86eb2c451bd8d6fff/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c#L7031). Finally, a request_sock is added in a "queue" [(which is a
hash-table actually)](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4d6d4c7f541d7027beed4fb86eb2c451bd8d6fff/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c#L7051) and a [syn-ack is sent](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4d6d4c7f541d7027beed4fb86eb2c451bd8d6fff/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c#L7053). So, for now I have no
evidence that a child socket is created on a syn-packet-processing stage.

Then, a client sends an ack. As on a syn processing step, a socket is
looked up. From what I've seen, this socket is still a listening socket.
But, there is a clause checking whether [sk->sk_state == TCP_NEW_SYN_RECV](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4d6d4c7f541d7027beed4fb86eb2c451bd8d6fff/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c#L2027). I've looked for places where this state is set and all I could find
was a request_sock ireq_state is set to TCP_NEW_SYN_RECV during a syn
packet processing. So, does __inet_lookup_skb procedure return a
request_sock created on a syn processing step, wrapped into some sock
struct? If not, what does it return, a listening socket? If yes, does it
really have a state TCP_NEW_SYN_RECV?! I haven't found anywhere that a
listening socket status can be TCP_NEW_SYN_RECV. However, I'm inclined to
believe that this if-clause is what I'm looking for, since a [tcp_check_req](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4d6d4c7f541d7027beed4fb86eb2c451bd8d6fff/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c#L2070) invoked there [creates a child socket](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4d6d4c7f541d7027beed4fb86eb2c451bd8d6fff/net/ipv4/tcp_minisocks.c#L807) by [cloning a listening socket](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4d6d4c7f541d7027beed4fb86eb2c451bd8d6fff/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c#L1570).

If that if-clause is not executed, I guess I will find myself in
[tcp_v4_do_rcv](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4d6d4c7f541d7027beed4fb86eb2c451bd8d6fff/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c#L1730) again. There, a synsookie is checked, and if there is one, a
[listening socket is cloned](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4d6d4c7f541d7027beed4fb86eb2c451bd8d6fff/net/ipv4/syncookies.c#L448). Procedure tcp_get_cookie_sock() does
it [the same way](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4d6d4c7f541d7027beed4fb86eb2c451bd8d6fff/net/ipv4/tcp_minisocks.c#L807) as in a [previous paragraph](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4d6d4c7f541d7027beed4fb86eb2c451bd8d6fff/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c#L1570).

But my case is that there are no syncookies. So I end up in an
[tcp_rcv_state_process()](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4d6d4c7f541d7027beed4fb86eb2c451bd8d6fff/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c#L1744), a listening socket state is [TCP_LISTEN](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4d6d4c7f541d7027beed4fb86eb2c451bd8d6fff/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c#L6470), and in
case of an ack packet, this procedure [simply returns](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4d6d4c7f541d7027beed4fb86eb2c451bd8d6fff/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c#L6472).

So, what am I missing? Any clues, any thoughts?

Comment: You are very confused between sockets and ports, and between listening sockets and connected sockets. Too broad.

Comment: care to give a couple of hints?

Comment: "When a packet is received, a listening socket is looked up": no, a listening *port* is looked up. "A listener socket is attached": no it isn't. The 'request socket' was already created, according to you. There aren't two sockets per connection. "A `request_sock` is added in a queue": again, this is the original 'request socket', not yet another socket. From the application's point of view, the accepted socket is created by `accept()`, not before, whatever data structures may exist inside the kernel.

Comment: 1) so __inet_lookup_skb procedure looks up a port, not a socket? It returns a struct sock, it doesn't look like a port, or does it? 2) Setting a rsk_listener field of a request_sock structure means "a listener socket is attached to a request_sock", why it's not the case? 3) request_sock is a temporary data structure, it's not a connection socket. It stores an info about a connection request, so it's more appropriate to refer to it a "connection request" i think. It has nothing to do with sockets. 4) application is of no interest for me in this question, anyway, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Yeah, think I got it. When a request_sock is added in an ehash, it's cast to a sock struct. Then, this pseudo-socket is found during an ack-processing stage. Its [sk_state](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4d6d4c7f541d7027beed4fb86eb2c451bd8d6fff/include/net/sock.h#L380) field refers to the sock_common.skc_state -- the same field that [ireq_state](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4d6d4c7f541d7027beed4fb86eb2c451bd8d6fff/include/net/inet_sock.h#L79) refers to. So my guess was correct.